# C++ create a void for fix text

Tags: c#, c++

i'm making a SPRX for PS3 (Plugin C++)
I have a little problem, i want to edit the text on my game but the text using a char and after 1 char it's a . like this: M.a.i.n. .M.e.n.u.

If i want to add a text, i need add manualy a hex with 00 for add a . on the text it's annoying, so i got a code for fix that but it's for C#

Code C# for fixtext

```
   private string fixText(string fixStr)
        {
            int length = fixStr.Length;
            int startIndex = 1;
            int num3 = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (num3 >= length)
                {
                    fixStr = fixStr.Replace(".", "\0");
                    return (fixStr + "\0\0\0");
                }
                fixStr = fixStr.Insert(startIndex, ".");
                startIndex += 2;
                num3++;
            }
        }
```

It's look like this, but i need convert this to C++ so i have tried that:

Code converted to C++

```
const char* fixText(std::string fixStr)
    {
        int length = fixStr.length;
        int startIndex = 1;
        int num3 = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (num3 >= length)
            {
                fixStr = fixStr.replace(".", "\0");
                return (fixStr + "\0\0\0");
            }
            fixStr = fixStr.insert(startIndex, ".");
            startIndex += 2;
            num3++;
        }
    }
```

For info, i starting with C++ and i really don't know how to do that

It's saying a error on:
fixStr = fixStr.Replace(".", "\0");

and
return (fixStr + "\0\0\0");

and i don't know if my code will work

after that, i will call fixText on this:

```
    void DrawText(const char* wchar) //void for Draw Text with the fix text like "Main" converted to M.a.i.n. in the game
    {
        strcpy((char*)0x000000, fixText(wchar)); //0x000000 it's the offset
    }
```

Hope you will understand what i mean, sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Comment: You are trying to return a `std::string` from a function which is marked to return a `const char*`. Use `return (fixStr + "\0\0\0").c_str();` instead or change the return type of your function `fixText`.

Comment: Use `std::replace(fixStr.begin(), fixStr.end(), '.', '\0');` instead of `fixStr = fixStr.replace(".", "\0");`. Don't forget to include `<algorithm>` for `std::replace`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help it's keep saying a error on the + : error: no operator "+" matches these operands operand types are: std::string + const char [4]

Comment: Try using `fixStr + std::string("\0\0\0")` or better `fixStr.append("\0\0\0")`

Comment: Same error, No operator "+" matches these operands operand types are: std::string + std::string

Comment: Well it should had worked with the earlier case also(`std::string + const char [4]` one). I think you've not included `<string>` header in your code.

Comment: Now all is good, 0 error but when i build it's say: error 301: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function and it's show:  int length = fixStr.length;

Comment: Change it to `int length = fixStr.length();` . Well, better use `auto` or `size_t` in place of `int`, but then you'll have to also change `int num3;` to `size_t num3;`.

Comment: Okay all is good, but i got a error when i try to add this in my void DrawText like this:

void DrawText(std::string wchar)
 {
  strcpy((char*)Draw_Text, fixText(wchar));
 }

 Error 5 error 20: identifier "fixText" is undefined C:\Users\rstei\Bureau\MC SPRX DEMO\MC\Functions.h 27 27 MC

Comment: You haven't put `fitText` function in the same file in which you are using `DrawText`. You need to include the header in which you've defined `fitText`.

Comment: I have add fixText and Drawtext in the same file called Functions.h

Comment: Have you defined `fitText` before `DrawText`? If not move your definition of `fitText` to top...